# Разработка настольного приложения для анализа данных

Tags: c#, wpf, java, swing

Доброго времени суток.
У меня на работе начинается новый проект по разработке приложения для анализа статистических данных. Приложение будет работать с базой данных sql server. ОС Windows. Но есть нюанс... 
Мое место работы - это государственное учреждение, где требуется работа с информацией, имеющей гриф секретности. Устанавливаться и использоваться ПО будет у нас.
Все бы ничего, но на рабочих машинах будущих пользователей будет установлено ПО Страж 3 и проведена аттестация рабочих мест на работу с секретными данными. Эта аттестация пройдет в ближайшее время, и как мне объяснили, после данного мероприятия изменять конфигурацию рабочих машин пользователей не будет возможным (показания, правда, расходятся - я спрашивал троих человек, и трое дали разные варианты ответов). 
Суть такая - после аттестации менять железо и ПО на машинах будет нельзя (это худший вариант ответа). 
И тут возникает вопрос: а что лучше выбрать для разработки. Хочется устанавливать ПО пользователям с периодом в 2 недели, но там возникают трудности... для запуска java приложения необходимо дать права только на jre и потом не напрягать IT с просьбой установки или изменения паспорта компьютера и т.д. А вот для запуска wpf приложения потребуется каждый раз искать этих неуловимых товарищей и привлекать к обновлению ПО у пользователя на машине.
Что посоветуете выбрать java swing или wpf? Трудности я приблизительно постарался описать. Опыт есть с обоими платформами.

Comment: увольняйся оттуда, не связывайся, гос тайну ты уже почти разболтал.

Comment: @eicto ну да как то странно спрашивать это тут

Comment: Что он тут разболтал? Человек попросил адекватно высказаться на тему предпологаемых технологий. Про тайну было сказано, чтобы описать, что нужно будет все аттестовать и лишний раз не поменяешь.

Answer (score 4):

Из моего опыта -- Swing намного неудобнее, нелогичнее, медленнее и просто хуже WPF, что вопросов вообще никогда не возникало. Хотя на Swing'е в принципе *можно* создать нормально выглядящее приложение, по факту нативные виджеты выглядят в стиле Motif/CDE, layout manager отвратителен (некоторые свойства действуют в одном случае и не действуют в другом, простое выравнивание вправо/влево сопряжено с нетривиальными танцами с бубном), визуальный редактор производит код, глядя в который хочется плакать, нету XAML, binding'ов, стилей, анимации, кодировать приходится в стиле WinForms, 19 век, в общем.

Кроме того, ваш опыт разработчика на WPF пригодятся на рынке труда существенно больше, чем опыт в Swing, всё же Java не снискала славы десктопного языка.

Резюме: если есть возможность, выбирайте WPF.

---

> А вот для запуска wpf приложения потребуется каждый раз искать этих неуловимых товарищей и привлекать к обновлению ПО у пользователя на машине.

Ы? Один раз устанавливаете .NET 4.5 и всё. Если вы говорите об обновлениях, то обновляются все -- и .NET, и Java, и эти обновления при необходимости вполне можно отключить на уровне групповых политик (спросите вашего админа, он знает лучше).

Answer (score 3):

Если честно, не понял, почему с WPF сложней. Мне кажется, стоит выбрать WPF.

Comment: Есть локальная сеть. Она предназначена для работы с гос тайной. В ней компы с windows xp. На каждом из них стоит программа "Страж", которая имеет список исполняемых файлов, которым разрешается запускаться. Все это аттестуется в ФСБ. После аттестации нельзя менять конфигурацию оборудования и ПО (как говорит наш специалист по информационной безопасности). Если что-то поменялось, то надо проводить новую аттестацию. wpf шикарная штука, но ПО на ней это исполняемый файл.

Comment: После каждой установки моего приложения на данные компы (нужно будет в течении года периодически обновлять ПО у пользователей данной сети) нужно будет настраивать этот Страж, чтобы он бинарнику разрешал запускаться. Плюс необходимость переаттестации компов (если это не так, то нашего спеца по безопасности нужно уволить). Тут суть вопроса больше в том, с чем проще в такой ситуации будет работать, а не что лучше.

Comment: Не понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под бинарником? В чем отличие запуска WPF приложения и swing?

Comment: Пардон. exe исполняемый файл. Эта система Страж разрешает запускать только то, что у нее прописано. Страж определяет исполняемый файл по хэш коду файла. Любое изменение требует перенастройки Стража. Если кто-то уже сталкивался с такой ситуацией, то пожалуйста посоветуйте что-нибудь.

Comment: а в чем тогда различие Java swing будет? Дотнетовские экзешники точно также в песочнице исполняются

Comment: В этом случае потребуется настройка на запуск только для jre. В этом случае получиться без особых проблем регулярно устанавливать ПО пользователям.

Comment: А если делать не десктопное приложение, а к примеру на ASP.NET ?
Это уже будет серверная часть правда, но тогда для работы вообще нужен один только браузер. Как собственно и для Java тоже можно так сделать. (Хотя java-апплет, все равно запускает jre).